# How to activate/find the Open Atrium Wiki in D7 OA 2.19

Tags: drupal, wiki, intranet

I am trying to activate the wiki in Open Atrium 7.x-2.19. I have the module enabled and set up a group and spaces and sections but cannot find/get to the wiki. All OA modules are activated and all blocks enabled.

Where is it, how do you get to it?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 ??? similarly stymied by this